# MS Access / VBA Code: How to combine these 2 procedures

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a VBA novice trying to combine these two sub procedures into a single procedure - can anyone provide how to do this?

Basically, I'm trying to add an image to an Access report (in the 2nd code block - it's checking/creating the image path) - where there is already a check for other information from the database product record.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

Dim x$, y$, i%

x = ""
For i = 1 To 10
    y = Me("txtOp" & i) & ""
    If y > "" Then
        If x > "" Then x = x & "  "
        x = x & "Option " & i & ": " & y
    End If
Next
If x > "" Then x = CR & x
Me.txtProduct = Me.txtItem & "" & x

If Me.Adjustment Then
    Me.txtShowSKU = ""
Else
    Me.txtShowSKU = Me.txtSKU
End If



Dim x, y, OK%
OK = False
x = Me.txtImage & ""
If x > "" Then
    y = getparm("ImagePath")
    If y > "" Then
        If Right$(y, 1) <> "\" Then y = y & "\"
        If Left$(x, 1) = "\" And Len(x) > 1 Then x = Mid$(x, 2)
        If FileExists(y & x) Then OK = True: x = y & x
    End If

    If OK Then
        Me.imgProd.visible = True
        Me.imgProd.Picture = x
    Else
        Me.imgProd.visible = False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code sample only shows one subroutine. Is this your combined result?

Comment: Thanks for the response Dean, but I don't understand your comment. Yes, there is only one subroutine above, but I need the two statements combined into one (there are 3 line breaks separating the two portions of code), I don't know how to make both functions run, and I believe you can only have one "Dim" statement per subroutine? Does that make any sense? Thanks!

Comment: You can only `Dim` a variable once, but you can re-initialise it as many times as you like. Instead of using `Dim x, y, OK%`, try just setting x and y to "". You still need to Dim `OK%` as that hasn't been declared before. By the way, the shorthand notation for declaring type is not good practice these days. It is preferable to use `Dim x as string`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dean, I really appreciate both yours and HK1's help - that info taught me how to make it work. As you mentioned, just changing the following also makes it work: 
Dim x, y, OK% into: 
Dim OK%
y = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Dim x as String
    Dim y as String
    Dim i as Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        y = Me("txtOp" & i) & ""
        If y > "" Then
            If x > "" Then x = x & "  "
            x = x & "Option " & i & ": " & y
        End If
    Next
    If x > "" Then x = CR & x
    Me.txtProduct = Me.txtItem & "" & x

    If Me.Adjustment Then
        Me.txtShowSKU = ""
    Else
        Me.txtShowSKU = Me.txtSKU
    End If

    Dim OK as Boolean
    y = ""

    x = Me.txtImage & ""
    If x > "" Then
        y = getparm("ImagePath")
        If y > "" Then
            If Right$(y, 1) <> "\" Then y = y & "\"
            If Left$(x, 1) = "\" And Len(x) > 1 Then x = Mid$(x, 2)
            If FileExists(y & x) Then OK = True: x = y & x
        End If

        If OK Then
            Me.imgProd.visible = True
            Me.imgProd.Picture = x
        Else
            Me.imgProd.visible = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```